# Implement interface of fragment in multiple activities

Tags: android

Ok so i have an activity A that has a fragment A, and an Activity B that has a fragment B. Activity A is the main screen(like a login screen). Now in fragment B, i try to do some work and when there is a session expired, i send a message, logout and go back to the main screen A.

Now fragment B has an interface which it uses to communicate with the Activity B for other different functions. Should My Activity A implement this same interface of fragment B just for this logout session or is there a better way?

An illustration:

```
public class fragmentB extends Fragment {


    public interface FragmentBProgressListener {
        public void onShowDataDialog();
        public void onRemoveData();
        public void onSessionError(String errordata);
    }


   //or should i have another interface that implements this only in activity A 

}
```

Activity B:

```
public class ActivityB extends Activity implements FragmentBProgressListener {


    public void onShowDataDialog(){

      }


     public void onRemoveData(){

    }


    public void onSessionError(String errordata){
          // finish Activity here
   }


}
```

Activity A:

```
public class ActivityA extends Activity implements FragmentAListener, FragmentBFragmentBProgressListener {


     public void onFragA(){

   }


     public void onShowDataDialog(){

      }


     public void onRemoveData(){

    }


    public void onSessionError(String errordata){
          // show error dialog here from fragment B
   }
}
```

is this a good way? any pitfalls i should be aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should My Activity A implement this same interface of fragment B just for this logout session or is there a better way?

You could always split the `onSessionError()` method out into another interface.

Comment: i was thinking of doing that but i don't know how to add multiple listeners to activities in onAttach().

Comment: @sparrow: I have no idea what you are talking about. When a fragment wishes to call a method on its hosting activity, it calls `getActivity()`, casts the result to the appropriate interface, then calls a method on that interface.

Comment: what i meant was that if i do as you suggested in your answer, i would have to implement the other interface in Activity A so  how do i attach this in the onAttach() of fragment B, or i don't have to?

Comment: @sparrow: Sorry, I still have no idea what you are talking about. `onAttach()` has nothing to do with interfaces. The fragment will be attached to the activity whether the activity implements no interfaces, one interface, two interfaces, three interfaces, or ten million interfaces. When you wish to call a method on the relevant interface, call `getActivity()` and cast that to be the interface of interest, *at the point where you need the interface* (which probably will be sometime later than `onAttach()`).